# How to restrict input values in custom function in R?

Tags: r, function

I wrote a customized em algorithm functions. I have three parameters to be estimated. These three parameters are all between 0 and 1, and add up to 1. So I think I only need to put two parameters, alpha and beta, in my function, the third parameter will be 1-alpha-beta. My question is how to let the function know that these two input can only take values between 0 and 1?

Comment: What do you want the function to do in the case that one of the arguments is outside that range?

Comment: Or do you want somekind of constrained optimization?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite clear as to whether the function in question depends on these values (alpha, beta) or returns them...

Could it be as simple as:

```
fun1 <- function(a,b){
    if(a<=0 | b<=0) warning("value of a or b <=0")
    if(a>=1 | b>=1) warning("value of a or b >=1")
### now function does something
    a1 <- a
    b1 <- b
    return(c(a1, b1, (1 - a1 - b1)))
    }
```

Here, your're checking the input before running the function.

The function will still run but warns the user e.g.

```
> fun1(0.25, 0.5)
[1] 0.25 0.50 0.25
```

but

```
> fun1(1.25, -0.5)
[1]  1.25 -0.50  0.25
Warning messages:
1: In fun1(1.25, -0.5) : value of a or b <=0
2: In fun1(1.25, -0.5) : value of a or b >=1
```

See `?stop` if you want to halt execution due to the input values and return an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using one of R packages, like `mixtools`, that implement EM (expectation–maximization) algorithm, your question is actually not about R.

You have to make an algorithmic decision on how to restrict values of your parameters, `alpha` and `beta`. You are, probably looking for so called *constrained optimization*, as [Paul Hiemstra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1033808/paul-hiemstra) suggested. The decision would depend on statistical (or mathematical or physical etc.) meaning of the problem you are trying to solve.

If you are at the beginner level, I would recommend to start with the most simple and rigid approach: during the iterations, if your parameter gets out of the allowed interval, set its value to the corresponding limit. Something like this:

```
alpha = min(1, max(0, alpha))
```